# Physical device, to calculate time gained by speeding (when driving a car)

Tags: geometry

Suppose I'm driving and my co-driver is asking to speed up in order to arrive sooner. She doesn't have any maths logic so discussing is too abstract for her the small amount of time gained even by increasing 20 km/h over 30 min.

So I handle her a physical device, with two movable parts. One is to put the current speed, the other one for the distance remaining. Then it displays the time needed. Then she move the speed part and **directly** see the time gained.

I've done so far one simplified, that gives me for a fixed velocity and a choosen distance the time remaining. But I guess the final answer is much more complicated, so I need some input about these kind of solutions.

[personnal try on paper](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/IMG_2373.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The physical device you are trying to invent already exists – more accurately, it has existed. It is called [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule). Before electronic calculators became widely available, slide rules were used to perform calculations. In the 1970s, they became obsolete (because of electronic calculators), and unfortunately, they are not produced any more.

However, you can build your own slide rules to achieve your goal. The basic working principle of slide rules is to use logarithmic scales.

For tackling your problem, I suggest decomposing the problem into two less complicated problems that are easier to solve.

1. For a distance of 1 kilometer, how many seconds will I be faster if I drive at velocity $v_1$ instead of velocity $v_0$?
2. For a distance of $n$ kilometer, how many seconds will I be faster if I drive at velocity $v_1$ instead of velocity $v_0$?

Obviously, once you have the answer to question 1, you will get the answer to question 2 by multiplying by $n$.

So, how do you solve question 1? The answer is to create your own ruler with a logarithmic scale. If your minimum velocity is 30 km/h, a ruler of length 120mm will be sufficient. Write the velocities on the ruler, in the following manner: The marking for the velocity of $x$ km/h is put at position $\frac{3600}{x}$ mm. For example:

- At 20mm, you write 180km/h.
- At 24mm, you write 150km/h.
- At 30mm, you write 120km/h.
- At 45mm, you write 80km/h.
- At 90mm, you write 40km/h.
- At 120mm, you write 30km/h.

You can use this newly designed ruler in the following fashion: If you want to know how many seconds you are faster on a 1 km distance if you drive 150km/h instead of 120km/h, just measure the distance between 150km/h and 120km/h with a standard ruler. The distance is 6mm, which means that you are 6 seconds faster.

For performing the multiplication for question 2, you can also use the slide rule principle.

(Of course, you can also use imperial units like miles and inches instead of the SI units, if you like.)